# Can't execute ANT from code

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, antrunner

I'm using Eclipse Helios and I have ANT file to do some task (compile java code).
But I can't execute the ANT file using code. These are my code:

```
AntRunner runner = new AntRunner();
runner.setBuildFileLocation(fileDir);
runner.setArguments("-Dmessage=Building -verbose");
```

When I run it, I got this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.ant.core.AntRunner
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:506)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at nz.ac.auckland.cs.marama.model.hotdeployment.HotDeployClassLoader.loadClassByParent(HotDeployClassLoader.java:83)
at nz.ac.auckland.cs.marama.model.hotdeployment.HotDeployClassLoader$RuntimeClassLoader.loadClass(HotDeployClassLoader.java:144)
at nz.ac.auckland.cs.marama.userdirectory.tools.MaramaEssential.handlers.visualhandlers.usertriggeringhandlers.ExecuteTestSuite.executeTestSuite(ExecuteTestSuite.java:57)
at nz.ac.auckland.cs.marama.userdirectory.tools.MaramaEssential.handlers.visualhandlers.usertriggeringhandlers.ExecuteTestSuite.notifyChanged(ExecuteTestSuite.java:41)
at nz.ac.auckland.cs.marama.editor.MaramaEditorContextMenuProvider$UserEventAction.run(MaramaEditorContextMenuProvider.java:197)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)
```

Can anyone tell me what this means? I can execute ANT using Eclipse right click function but I can't invoke it through my code.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that `AntRunner` isn't on your classpath. The class you're using is a part of Eclipse. You would need to find which JAR from Eclipse contains that class and add it to your classpath.

Alternatively, I would recommend you use a different approach to launch your Ant build. A quick Google search turned up [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0502_gawor/0502_gawor.html), for example.

Comment: Wasn't AntRunner is bundle inside Ant? Does this mean I need to set an AntRunner in my classpath?

Comment: I would expect that `org.**eclipse**.ant.core.AntRunner` is included in one of Eclipse's jars, not Ant's. Couldn't tell you which one. Is there a reason you want to use Eclipse's AntRunner?

Comment: Thanks for the info Issac. I want to AntRunner because I want to execute my Ant file (it will compile java n junit test).

Comment: Yes, but why _that_ method of running your Ant build? Why using a part of the Eclipse project instead of something that's actually shipped with Ant? See my updated answer with a link to another method of running Ant.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have tried it previously and get this error at p.init(): 'Exception in thread main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/launch/AntMain at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)' It really bug me because from what I read, they solve this issues in ant.1.8

Comment: I just found the solution for the error I mention previously, you need to add another jar - 'ant-launcher.jar' to the external jar library.